# No module psutil.error

Tags: python, pip

I have the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/a8/terminals.py", line 11, in <module>
    import psutil, psutil.error
ImportError: No module named error
```

psutil is installed.

Comment: There is no psutil.error module,check you import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`psutil` has `NoSuchProcess`, `AccessDenied` and `TimeoutExpired` exceptions. There is class `Process` in `psutil` but `error` is not valid attribute for `psutil`.

Comment: From source code https://code.google.com/p/psutil/source/browse/psutil/__init__.py there is `Error` class but not `error`. Please ask aliafshar for that.

Comment: Thanks, I recode the exception to AccesDenied and delete the import psutil.error.

Comment: psutil.error.py module was removed in 2.0.0 version